# Can someone tell me why am I getting "none" as an output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

the output I'm getting is:
Your grade is X
none
I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of none.

```py
def computegrade (scr):
    score = float (scr)
    if score >= 0.9 :
        print ("Your grade is A")
    elif score >= 0.8 :
        print ("Your grade is B")
    elif score >= 0.7 :
        print ("Your grade is C")
    elif score >= 0.6 :
        print ("Your grade is D")
    elif score < 0.6 :
        print ("Your grade is F")
    else :
        print ("Enter digits you moron")

scr = input("What was your score?\n")
print (computegrade (scr))
```

Comment: You do not return anything, that is why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `return` statement to actually return a value from a function. Here you just `print`, so you do not actually return anything, or, more accurately, you return None, which is then printed according to your last line.

Just replace your `print()` with `return`, eg `return "Your grade is F"` and you'll be good.